# VSCode (on win10) keeps asking for ssh (to remote Ubutnu) password, ssh key is properly set up

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys, vscode-remote

- I'm running VSCode (with remote develop) on Windows 10.
- I have generated a ssh key and want to use it to connect to remote server (Ubuntu) via SSH (instead of password).
- VSCode keeps asking for the password. For another server, with the same key, it works.
- The key is properly installed in the server. If I try to ssh via cygwin with the key, it works.
- The tab `OUTPUT`/`Remote-SSH` shows:

  `> warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of plain `ssh-keygen` without arguments, use (for instance):

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521
```

Apparently the problem is created by three concurrent factors: (1) outdated ssh client shipped with windows, (2) the newer versions of the server in modern Linux, (3) using the standard rsa key generated by default by ssh-keygen. It's also reproducible from the windows command line calling ssh.

Another option is to manually overwrite the openSSH binaries under System32

[Source](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1263)